# PHPStorm jump over words and break at underscores

Tags: navigation, phpstorm

I'm wondering if there's a quick, convenient, way to jump over words in a class declaration and break on the underscore rather than the entire phrase e.g:

class My_Example_Class_Goes_Something_Like_This extends Another_Class_Name_Thats_Separated_By_Underscores { }

alt + left/right arrows works great for jumping words but any idea how pstorm can be customised to jump over class names separated by underscores?

Comment: 1) I'm sorry ... but could you clarify what do you actually want: jump over whole class in one go .. or stop at each underscore 2) this affects not just class names but ALL identifiers (class names, variables etc etc). If you want for **class names ONLY** -- then it's definitely not possible.

Comment: Say what? alt + arrows switches tabs for me. ctrl + arrow is normal behavior for any editor (not just phpstorm)

Comment: @MikeB on a Mac alt steps over words, ctrl + arrows switches spaces.

Comment: @LazyOne stop at underscores would be the desired outcome and thinking about it all identifiers would be perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Use "CamelHumps" words**

[image]

**P.S.**
Please note that this will also work for `NameWithNoUderscoresButWithCapitalLetters`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Instantly made my life better.